# Application server error when deployment an app inside other app IIS. The type X exists in both A and B

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, web-config

I already have an application under IIS and, inside, another one. The main application works properly but when I try to access to the second one thorugh a link I get the message 'Application server error' The type X exists in 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files...' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files...'

I have read about this issue and I tried every solution and nothing worked for me. Like stop IIS and remove Temporary ASP.NET Files folders, changing the authentication in IIS to specific user/application user, viewing the IIS log, checking the .net version, adding permission to IIS APPPOOL user to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder... It works on local environment but no in production server.

I think it's a matter of permissions but I can't get it solved. Is there anything else that I missed?

Comment: I suggest you could try to clear the project's Bin and Obj folders in your development environment and republish the whole project to IIS.

Comment: I tried that too

Comment: Could you please tell how you have application under IIS and, inside, another one? Do you mean you add the web application directly into another web application without creating the nested web appplication or vitual directory?

Comment: What I meant is that I added a New Website and, nested, a new Application. Sorry if i didn't explain myself.